# How to change colour of text when using document.getElementById("id").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to change the text of a span to something else when a particular event occurs. I am doing this as :

```
document.getElementById("usernameError").innerHTML = "**Message";
```

I want to display the same in a different colour. Any idea on how to do that? 
Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to change the color in the same line? You can simply use  `document.getElementById("usernameError").style.color` function in the next line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always just put the message in a span and put a style attribute on it. This should do it:

```
document.getElementById("usernameError").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>**Message</span>";
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can find in the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), you can use `HTMLElement.style` property to change any style on the element.

So you can do something like this to colour it in red:

```
 document.getElementById("usernameError").style.color = '#d00'
```

Answer (score 1):

A more future proof and reusable solution would probably be to add a class to either the current element or the span element, depending on your requirements:

```
document.getElementById("usernameError").className = "color-red";
```

Or working off Erics solution:

```
document.getElementById("usernameError").innerHTML = "<span class='color-red'>**Message</span>";
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.color-red{
    color: #F00;
}
```

You could obviously also add diff colours and attribute in a much more maintainable way like this.

NOTE: [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) Returns A String, representing the class, or a space-separated list of classes, of an element.